# django google app engine error

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am absolutely new to django development, and trying my hands on google app engine because of some requirement in the company. i am getting this error while trying to do manage.py syncdb.

> Error: No module named appengine_django

Here are my files:
settings.py

```
 # Django settings for blogproject project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# URL prefix for admin media -- CSS, JavaScript and images. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/media/", "/media/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'p1!_$6n7#wet&ibfx+p&y!gfo!vegjgdz9-#us5gj7dir)d)n0'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',

)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'blogproject.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'appengine_django',
    'blogproject.blogs',

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'blogproject.blogs.views.index'),

    )
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from blogs.poll import models
import bforms
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def render(template, payload):
    payload['recents'] = models.Poll.all().order('-created_on').fetch(5)
    return render_to_response(template, payload)

def index(request):
    polls = models.Poll.all().order('-created_on').fetch(20)
    payload = dict(polls = polls)
    return render('index.html', payload)

def create(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        pollform = bforms.PollForm()
        choiceforms = []
        for i in range(4):
            choiceforms.append(bforms.ChoiceForm(prefix = 'f%s'%i))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pollform = bforms.PollForm(request.POST)
        choiceform = bforms.ChoiceForm()
        if pollform.is_valid():
            poll = pollform.save()
            choiceforms = []
            for i in range(4):
                choiceforms.append(bforms.ChoiceForm(poll=poll, prefix = 'f%s'%i, data=request.POST))
            for form in choiceforms:
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(poll.get_absolute_url())
    payload = dict(pollform=pollform, choiceforms=choiceforms)
    return render('create.html', payload)

def poll_detail(request, poll_key):
    poll = models.Poll.get(poll_key)
    choices = models.Choice.all().filter('poll = ', poll)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        choice_key = request.POST['value']
        choice = models.Choice.get(choice_key)
        choice.votes += 1
        choice.put()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('./results/')
    payload = dict(poll = poll, choices = choices)
    return render('poll_details.html', payload)

def poll_results(request, poll_key):
    poll = models.Poll.get(poll_key)
    choices = models.Choice.all().filter('poll = ', poll)
    payload = dict(poll = poll, choices = choices)
    return render('poll_results.html', payload)
```

models.py

```
from appengine_django.models import BaseModel
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Poll(db.Model):
    question = db.StringProperty()
    created_on = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = 1)
    created_by = db.UserProperty()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' %self.question

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/poll/%s/' % self.key()


class Choice(db.Model):
    poll = db.ReferenceProperty(Poll)
    choice = db.StringProperty()
    votes = db.IntegerProperty(default = 0)
```

Please help me with this.

thanks

Comment: Well, you don't appear to have `appengine_django` installed, whatever that is. What is it? Why do you think you need it? What documentation are you following?

Comment: @daniel...thanks for replying man..even i tried to find out what it is.. here is the tutorial i am following. http://www.doboism.com/blog/tag/google-app-engine/ Or can you suggest me a tutorial which is good enough to show how to run a simplestttt django app in GAE?

Comment: Where did you find that? It's completely outdated. Lycha has the link to the proper tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

You should use Django-nonrel when using Django in AppEngine. [Google introduction.](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/appengine/articles/django-nonrel.html)

It seems you are trying to use django application called appengine_django that can not be resolved. Do you have it installed? How did you install it?

Comment: I was just following this tutorial http://www.doboism.com/blog/tag/google-app-engine/...and thats when I got this error..if I remove it..i get this error:  from appengine_django.models import BaseModel ImportError: No module named appengine_django.models

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you for a recent complete django implementation:
http://allbuttonspressed.com
You can probably achieve what you want without patching in all of django though. Just try an example from the manual and build on it, some of the django stuff that are not included are form preview, plugins, extension but the django templating system is builtin with GAE, so I'd first make an analyses whether your project actually requires full django or could do with something like I use namely Jinja2 + WTFOrms + python 2.7 GAE = My stack.